# Declare and use range in vba

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am quite new to VBA,
Today developing a macro I noticed something funny.

Using `Range` like this is working :

```
Dim rg As Range     
Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")
```

Using `Range` like this does not work and result in error "Object variable not set" :

```
Dim rg As Range   
rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")
```

but using `Range` like this is working :

```
Dim rg,rg2 As Range  
rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")
```

How is it possible?

Comment: I believe you'll find that it doesn't "really" work it just doesn't trigger the compiler error when compiling.  For example, add `Debug.Print rg.Address` at the end and it will only work when you use `Set`

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/17877644/11683, with the addition of http://stackoverflow.com/a/19234210/11683.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are discovering `Variant` and object references.

A `Range` is an *object* - a `Variant` can be *anything* **including** an object.

This is the correct way to go about it:

```
Dim rg As Range     
Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")
```

Because:

1. You're explicitly declaring `rg` as being a `Range` object.
2. You're correctly assigning the object reference with the `Set` keyword.

---

If you don't specity the `Set` keyword, you're assigning an object reference using the VBA syntax for *values* assignments, and that's an error:

```
rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")
```

If you declare multiple variables in the same instruction, and only specify a type for the last one, then `rg` is a `Variant` here:

```
Dim rg,rg2 As Range  ' this is like doing Dim rg As Variant, rg2 As Range
rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")
```

And VBA will happily let you assign a `Variant` with just about *anything*... but things will blow up at run-time.

Comment: + 1 - To confirm your reasoning here is a link to cpearson, scroll to [Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx)

Comment: May be everybody knows it but anyway ... if ```rg``` is declared as  ```Variant``` then ```rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")``` assigns values of "A1:B2" to rg (no error occures). ```rg``` is then array of Varaints ```(1 to 2, 1 to 2)```.

Comment: @retailcoder yeah it is fun :-). I checked it in object browser and ```Value``` is not the default property of ```Range``` ... at least in my Excel version which is 2007. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877536/vba-when-one-should-use-set-e-g-for-specialcells-return-value/17877644#17877644

Comment: @MathieuGuindon you are right, let me rephrase (I deleted my previous comment):
multiple variables declaration (including the type definition) can be done in "the same instruction" using the correct syntax. I expanded on that in a [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57942548/2089396).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Mathieu Guidon's answer:

If you want to specify two objects in the same instruction (one line), you should use the following syntax:

```
Dim rg as Range, rg2 As Range
```

This will correctly assign both `rg` and `rg2` as a range object.

Using `Dim rg, rg2 As Range`, only rg2 is assigned as a range object (rg becomes a Variant), as Mathieu Guidon correctly explains.