# VBA/Excel: why does the match() method not work for all "types" of ranges

Tags: excel, vba

Playing around with the [match()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) method I found out that match() only works for search ranges referencing single rows and columns (e.g. `B1:B5` or `A2:F2`) (one dimensional ranges) not for a range like (`A1:E5`) (two dimensional range).

Why is that? As far as I understand both "types" of ranges are essentially arrays/array-references (which is the only thing required by [Microsoft's reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match)). Is it my understanding or does the match() method work funky?

I tried to research this issue myself, but there is nothing pointing to that issue in the reference (as SJR points out correctly).

Here's the code where I get an error as a result. Using e.g. `B1:B5` works fine. The value I'm looking for is in cell `B2`.

```
'Set Search Range
    Dim rngSearchRange As Range
    Set rngSearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:E5")

'Set Search Term  
    Dim searchTerm As String
    searchTerm = "test"

'Set Compare Type
    Dim compareType As Integer
    compareType = 0

'Execute Search
    Dim found As Variant
    found = Application.Match(searchTerm, rngSearchRange, compareType)
```

Note: This is a followup question on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960956/). Using find() is not an option at least not in a general case since find() depends on the presentation of the value.

Comment: Can't see it in the documentation but fairly sure MATCH only works on single rows/columns. You could use `Find` instead.

Comment: Match returns the position inside the array of whatever it matches with as a number, but this only works in a single direction. If there is more dimensions to the range it couldn't output a single match number like "Match no. 4" but had to say "Match no. row 1 col 3" which is simply not what Match is designed for. As @SJR recommended, use `FIND` instead.

Comment: Hadn't noticed that you stated this in your question and were asking why. Pass on that. I suppose the banal answer is that is how Microsoft programmed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way `MATCH` is designed is to return the number of the match in one specified direction. By default, it counts the array in one direction, and returns which count the match occurs.
If there were more dimensions to the array, it couldn't return a single number as a match, since it would need to specify which row and column in the array the match was found, rather than just which cell matched.
Example data:

```
a   b   c   d   e
f   g   h   i   j
```

If you want to find value i, it would return 4 when searching the row, or 2 when searching the column. When searching the range, it would need to return both 4 and 2 simultaneously, which is not what it is designed to do.

In this case, it would be better to use the `Find` formula for this, as this would return a range object (direct reference to a cell) from which either the cell content or its address can be derived.

*Edit:* One could argue that it could return either 8 or 9, if it continued counting your range either per column or row. However this would complicate the formula exponentially and make much more room for unexpected results. I would assume the design team decided to make it as easy to use as possible so most base excel users can use the formula without any advanced logic knowledge.

Comment: Actually, I found out this is not the reason (at least not as I understand it). The method returns the address of the (first) cell, which you can use like this: `searchRange.Cells(searchResult)` - which is essentially an array (analog to the syntax of an array: array1D(i), array2D(i,j)). This essentially makes it impossible to return a result for a two-dimensional range/array, making it impossible to use a two-dimensional range/array. Keeping this explanation in mind the reference from Microsoft makes much more sense.

Comment: PS. I will delete the question if it stays on a negative score, but feel free to make a suggestion how I could improve it (or you can upvote it as well, if you like)

Comment: Hi @Albin, you're not wrong, but not quite correct either. [As per the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) the `Match` function returns a double, [which can only be a number, not address](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/double-data-type) but since you call it within your `searchrange` it will pick the number within that range and returns the right result. You are correct that it couldn't return an address in a two dimensional array, as a double data type can only be one single number.

Comment: Also your question was probably downvoted as you asked for an explanation, not a solution to a problem. Those types of questions are tricky on stackoverflow as people would encourage you to do your own research instead of using stackoverflow as a teacher. But since the documentation is vague at best, this is still a valid question. I would leave the question here for anyone who would stumble across the same issue in the future looking for a clear explanation. I did give you an upvote though ;)

Comment: thanks, but isn't an address essentially a number (at least in case of an array)?!

Comment: In the case of a one dimensional array, yes. But an address in excel would by definition have two bits of data, the column `A` and the row `1`. as so: `A1`. The `double` data type can only return one of these values, and therefore only works for searching in one direction. Simplified: If I told you to look at cell 32 in excel, you could look at row 32, or column AF (the 32nd column), either would be valid, but the cells are miles apart, so more complete info is needed.

Comment: That's what I mean, (according to the reference) match() doesn't actually search through a range, but goes through an array and returns an 8bit result, which *is* the address of a (one dimensional) array and not just "a number"?! Sort of an implicit definition of the searchRange/Array by the result. (A range, by definition, seems to be a one dimensional or a two dimensional array)?! I don't think it actually searches through one direction, I think it causes the error because of a type mismatch (1D and 2D array) (otherwise it would could find it in certain cases, which it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

Match looks through a one-dimensional array and returns the matching value's position (not a range, address, etc.). Match only returns a number indicating the position. For what you're trying to do `Find` should do the trick.

Comment: Find() not an option (see question's comments) but thanks anyway.

Comment: I found out it actually does return a (range) address (which can be seen as a position, but essentially I don't think what it is), plz see my comment under Plutian's answer.